# Winter bash feedback

Tags: discussion

SEI is asking for some feedback on Winter bash.

If you are interested, you can provide it here: [What do you think of Winter Bash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161188/)

Comment: You can't take away Slorlax's police hat!